# SQL CE azure connection

Tags: asp.net, azure, sql-server-ce, database-connection, azure-sql-database

I am using azure to publish an asp.net application, when I publish locally it works fine, but on Azure all things related with database isnt showing up and getting "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."

Wondering if it could be somthing wrong with my connection string.

http://webly.azurewebsites.net/

App_Data folder with webly_data.sdf
Bin: webly.dll ... Simple.Data.SqlCe40.dll

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="webly" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\webly_data.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I am using sdf, and dont know how azure leads with that...

------ PROBLEM SOLVED -------

[image]

I did the following:

1. Configure the website (at Azure Management)
2. Put the connection string there as Custom

Dont know exactly why this is required, maybe it was ignoring my connection strings in my web.config....
Thanks to who answered here.

Comment: Well set up Azure Diagnostic's Logging and find out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windowsazure/gg433048.aspx  ...but an .SDF file is fine with Azure. It has it's disadvantages but providing you are packaging the `sdf` file with your deploy package, it'll work

Comment: You need to deploy the sql compactcdll files to bin as well

Comment: Yeah, I did that... Thanks Arran and ErikEJ for your answers, but I find out what was going on...will post as answer... Many thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I did the following:

1. Configure the website (at Azure Management)
2. Put the connection string there as Custom

Dont know exactly why this is required, maybe it was ignoring my connection strings in my web.config....

Comment: Thank you man! I was fighting this problem for 3 hours :) 
Note that simply DELETING this string also works.