# SQLCompact connection error in azure web sites

Tags: azure

I am using the below connection string .This is working fine when I am in the azure web role but when I try to use this connection string in a azure web site I am getting this error 
The path is not valid. Check the directory for the database. [ Path = D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\Configuration.sdf ]

```
  <add name="Configuration"
       connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Configuration.sdf"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
```

Is there some other configuration needed for Azure web sites.

Update:
So I looked at this thread [Stack Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14938406/sql-ce-azure-connection) and this person has the same issue but he adds the database connection through azure management portal so I am sure it's supposed to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you didn't include Configuration.sdf in your project.

Right click the **App_Data\Configuration.sdf** and select include in project.

And re-publish it again, then it will be work.