# windows ce application can't connect to sql azure

Tags: vb.net, azure, windows-mobile, windows-ce, azure-sql-database

when a try to connect to sql azure database from windows ce application show "sql server requires encryption on"

i try adding device ip to sql azure firewall and i had used "encrypt=true" in connection string but not works, shows "unknown connection option in connection string encrypt"

i suspect that is necessary an ssl connection but i don't know how make it

when i try to make a desktop test it work perfectly

im using
-visual studio 2008
- windows ce 05
- sql azure

many thanks

Alejandro

Comment: if you are using azure, then why not use a database from azure? it also gives you the connection string?

Comment: yes i'm using sql azure and i try with this connection string but not works, show the same error

Comment: did you edit the "Insert Password Here" bit? (as well as within your app config file)

Comment: yes, I did. The aplication work perfectly from desktop but when i run in device show an error

Comment: that could be that Azure wants to know the IP address of the device - have a look in its docs!

Comment: i have enabled all ip in azure, and i try adding just ip of the device. and. nothing.. show the same error

Comment: you could also look at: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14938406/3436942

Comment: woww.. maybe it can useful, i will try. thank you for your help